# Drupal 8 cache failed to generate images

Tags: 8

I set cache max age to 30mins, hosted on VPS without any 3rd party cache driver installed. The problem is sometimes images are not properly generated for images which use image style, but when I flush the cache manually it fixed.

Any solution or probably similar problem? Thanks.